# how to find three positive integers $\mathbf a, \mathbf b, \mathbf a+\mathbf b$ each can be write as a sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory, integers

I need to find $\mathbf a, \mathbf b \in \Bbb Z^+$

such that $\mathbf a$ can be write as a sum of two squares

and $\mathbf b$ can be write as a sum of two squares

and $\mathbf a+\mathbf b$ can be write as a sum of two squares

is there are any ?

i tried to find but i can't thanks.

Comment: Have you tried actually looking for examples?  Are you allowing one of the squares to be $0$?

Comment: I have less knowledge about number theory, I try to use but it didn't succeed pythagorean triples, only positive integers are allowed

Comment: pythagorean triples consist of positive integers...

Comment: If you allow one of the squares to be $0$ then $a=b=1$ works.  You need to specify whether you are allowing one of the squares to be $0$.

Comment: only positive integers are allowed

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect all the constraints you have in mind.  If you want positive terms only then just use $a=b=5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP should have worked more.  If $0$ is counted as a square, then the smallest examples (i.e., smallest $a+b$) are $\{a,b\}=\{1,1\}$ if $a=b$ is possible, and $\{a,b\}=\{1,4\}$ if $a\neq b$ must hold.  If $0$ is not included, then the smallest examples (i.e., smallest $a+b$) are $\{a,b\}=\{5,5\}$ if $a=b$ is possible, and $\{a,b\}=\{5,8\}$ if $a\neq b$ must hold.  One does not need to know any positive integer above $13$ to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

$$a=3^2+4^2=25$$
$$b=6^2+8^2=100$$

$$a+b=125=10^2+5^2$$

The key to generating such pairs is to have a look at Pythagorean triples

Answer (score 1):

A positive integer $n$ is representable as the sum of two squares as $n=a^2+b^2$ only if every prime divisor $p\equiv3 \mbox{ mod }4$ of $n$ occurs with an even exponent.

Answer (score 1):

For the equation:

$$X_1^2+X_2^2=Y_1^2+Y_2^2+Y_3^2+Y_4^2$$

Solutions have the form:

$$X_1=t^2+2(p+s-y)t+k^2+2y^2+2p^2-4yp-2ys+4ps$$

$$X_2=t^2+2(p+s-y)t+k^2+2y^2+2s^2-2yp-4ys+4ps$$

$$Y_1=t^2+2(p+s-y)t+k^2+2y^2-2yp-2ys+2ps$$

$$Y_2=2(p+s-y)k$$

$$Y_3=2(p+s-y)(t+p+s-y)$$

$$Y_4=t^2+2(p+s-y)t+k^2+2ps$$

$k,y,t,p,s$ - integers asked us.

$$a=Y_1^2+Y_2^2$$

$$b=Y_3^2+Y_4^2$$